# unreadable SD card repairing - possible?

Tags: hardware, sd-card

Does it possible to mount and refresh broken SD card?

i had SD card, which doesn't readable by the system.

It was happened while testing process, i had write to card files 1GB value, and after about 255 or 260 such a file, it was crashed and becomes unreadable while it still attached to the system as mass storage device.

I had tried e2fsck, testdisk, badblocks and even chkdsk - they aren't find that device.
While dmesg show that it attached:

```
[ 5340.561375] /dev/sdb: Can't open blockdev
[ 6323.715239] usb 1-4.4: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 6341.104941] usb 1-4.4: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 6341.209213] usb 1-4.4: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[ 6341.210268] usb 1-4.4: New USB device found, idVendor=14cd, idProduct=1212, bcdDevice= 1.00
[ 6341.210276] usb 1-4.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=2
[ 6341.210278] usb 1-4.4: Product: Mass Storage Device
[ 6341.210280] usb 1-4.4: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 6341.210282] usb 1-4.4: SerialNumber: 121220160204
 6341.211397] usb-storage 1-4.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 6341.211684] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-4.4:1.0
[ 6342.221559] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Mass     Storage Device   1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 6342.221876] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 6342.370929] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Media removed, stopped polling
[ 6342.371360] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
lm@debian:~$
```

use any commands - the device is present, but unreadable

```
lm@debian:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINTS
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    58G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0   522M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0   8.4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda7   8:7    0  55.9G  0 part /
 sdb      8:16   1     0B  0 disk 
lm@debian:~$ sudo badblocks -s -p 2 -f -e 15 /dev/sdb
badblocks: No medium found while trying to determine device size

lm@debian:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/32
mount: /media/32: mount point does not exist.
   dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

lm@debian:~$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb
e2fsck 1.47.0 (5-Feb-2023)
```

e2fsck: No medium found while trying to open /dev/sdb

```
lm@debian:~$ sudo testdisk /log /dev/sdb
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org
Unable to open file or device /dev/sdb: No medium found

lm@debian:~$ sudo ntfsfix -d /dev/sdb
Mounting volume... Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: No medium found
Error opening '/dev/sdb': No medium found


lm@debian:~$ sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 /dev/sdb
mkfs.fat 4.2 (2021-01-31)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdb: No medium found

lm@debian:~$ ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  0 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  1 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  2 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda2
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  3 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda3
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  4 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda4
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  5 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda5
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  6 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda6
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  7 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda7
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8,  8 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sda8
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Sep 16 01:09 /dev/sdb
lm@debian:~$
```

Comment: There's a chance that what died was the reader. I'd at least check the card with another reader first if I were you.

Comment: as I am I, i had checked this card with all my availiable card readers yet before this topic created.

Answer (score 1):

Short story: Throw it out and buy a new one.

Longer story: Likely the device's internal driver has been broken, but that's just a wild guess. If you do not need data from it, I suggest doing the above.